# Usage of suffix in Arithmetic vs Arithmatic - arithmos (root)?

Tags: etymology

In creating a new English word, when does one use the suffix of -matic vs -metic?

As an example: Why or how does one get arithmetic from a root word of arithmos?

On the origins of the word "arithmetic" vs "arithmatic":

- Why is the suffix -metic? And not -matic?
- Why not arithmos-tic?

--

Note, this is a legitimate question regarding the etymology of a English word, that (albeit it) may have Greek origins, still belongs more here than elsewhere.

Comment: Are you referring to the noun, the adjective or both. The noun ("we studied arithmetic today") and adjective ("the following sequence is an example of an arithmetic progression") have the same spelling but different pronunciation.

Comment: There isn't a word 'arithmatic' revealed by a [dictionary search](https://onelook.com/?w=arithmatic&ls=a) (only four references, all saying 'not found'), but there was an early computer language called [ARITH-MATIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARITH-MATIC).

Comment: The etymology of 'arithmetic' is given [here](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=arithmetic&ref=searchbar_searchhint), but as to *why* – because it did.

Comment: Why was this question closed? Specifically I am curious about the etymology.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, anyone can google the etymology, but that doesn't answer my question on how it came to be.

Comment: It's a common English word that has Greek origins... @StuartF (also, arguably, it has French origins as well... so which is it? And, do we discount any word that has French origins in this StackExchange... in which case, isn't that a majority of the English language?

Comment: The question is phrased as if someone had coined the word recently, and you are questioning the validity of the "rules" they used to derive it. No-one is "using" that suffix: it is what has come about.

Comment: Why do you think it should have been arithmatic? The Greek word was  αριθμητικη, with an eta. Take it up with the Greeks.

Answer (score 0):

"Arithmatic" is a [misspelling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arithmatic) of *arithmetic*

In my dialect of American English, when used as an adjective, like in *arithmetic progression*, it is pronounced as /æɹ.ɪθ.ˈmæ.tɪk/, unlike the noun version: /ə.'ɹɪθ.mə.tɪk/.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which asks why the correct spelling isn't arithmatic.

Comment: Questions about why a certain  word is not spelled a certain way have no answers. Naturally they aren't addressed seriously.

Comment: @JohnLawler This isn't just any word. This word seems rather an exceptional one, due to its commonness.

Comment: Perhaps it used to be common; but nowadays it's usually just called "math" (or "maths" in the UK).

Comment: What is your dialect (which pronounces it '/æɹ.ɪθ.ˈmæ.tɪk/ progression')? I've never heard that before. I think I've only ever heard  '/æɹ.ɪθ.ˈmɛ.tɪk/ progression' GenAmE (the DRESS vowel).

Comment: This is possibly idiosyncratic but I have pronounced it this way and not been corrected

Comment: I addressed what I assumed was a question about why sounds don't always match spelling -- it's not "matic" because despite sounding that way (in my perhaps idiolect) English doesn't have a 1:1 spelling sound correspondence